# Magento 2 - overwrite module Less / css with theme

Tags: magento-2.1, module, theme, css

I currently have a module installed inside of the following directory:

> httpdocs/vendor/module/module-name

I've installed the module with composer and it works. However I've noticed the module is adding its own styles to the style sheets (obviously its going to it has less files in it), I want to remove the styles that the module is adding, using my theme.

The current location the module is making the styles is:

> module/module-name/web/css/source/module.less

[image]

Style.css is empty - and I assume this is for custom styles as this doesn't get compiled into the main style sheets.

Do i go about it by creating the module inside of my theme and overwriting it like i do all ***magento*** core ones, or should I overwrite the module and stop it loading the styles all together.

My main issue is i want to remove the styles all together without touching the original module (they're annoying me) - as im sure that will get updated and i'd like to keep it up to date through composer.

**The styles are very intrusive and break my layout** - any help would be awesome

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Put an empty file in here `{theme}/Vendor_Module/web/css/source/_module.less`. The blank file will override the module's `_module.less` file. You shouldn't need to bother with the other `.less` files.

Then you have to clear the static content so that Less gets recompiled : `rm -rf pub/static/* var/view_preprocessed/*`.

Comment: yep worked. I tried this, but i forgot to clear the pub/static and preprocessed. Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

How the module call the css file? Is it called in the head via any xml layout?

You probably can do the following in one of your theme layout file:

```
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <head>
        <remove src="name.css"/>
    </head>
</page>
```

http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/frontend-dev-guide/layouts/xml-manage.html#layout_markup_css_remove

Comment: Isn't called into the header via the XML seems to be loaded differently. This was my original thoughts, as i could just remove it. Seems to compile into the base css/styles-l.css and css/styles-m.css

Comment: Could you please describe the web/css files names and structure

Comment: Edited question to show what im working with.